# Nginx error recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx

i am use dedicated server with webuzo as panel. since the first installation i have two error problem with my nginx server. i have error like this:

> (1) 2015/11/01 18:41:45 [error] 6806#0: *68294 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.187.100.154, server: domain.com, request: "GET /ebook/q/pdf/Women-Pioneers-of-Public-Education-How-Culture-Cam-.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "domain.com", referrer: "http://domain.com/"
>
> (2) 2015/11/01 18:38:48 [error] 6806#0: *67648 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 87.213.232.155, server: domain.com, request: "GET /ebook/q/pdf/Prentice-Hall-Chemistry-Assessment-Answers-Chapter-18.html HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "domain.com", referrer: "http://domain.com"

please advice me what should i do with that error? because that is make my load server too slow and send me nightmare everyday.....please help me guys

regards

Comment: It's as the error message says, the peer (the other side of the connection, i.e. the upstream server) is closing the connection. Ask whoever administers the upstream server why it closes the connection; maybe you're reaching some sort of resource limit or abuse prevention mechanism, maybe their server crashes.

Comment: My server is unmanaged sir.